# Unicode for hindi printing on Zebra ZDR series printer

Tags: unicode

I am trying to print Unicode (for Hindi printing) using ZPL on Zebra printer ZDR500R. I am sending unicode file through 'Send file' in 'Tools' properties of Zebra printer. I have used various fonts like `'NT20WGL4.FNT', 'NK20WGL4.FNT', 'MONOBD15.FNT', H24.FNT', 'H12.FNT'` etc. But none of them worked to print Hindi.
 I am using following code for printing.

```
----------------------------------------------
^XA
^LH100,150
^CWT,E:MONOBD1524.FNT
^CFT,30,30
^CI28
^FT0,0^FH^FDTesting 1 2 3^FS
^FT0,50^FH^FD_905_924_93E_930_93F^FS
^FT0,100^B3^FDAAA001^FS
^XZ
-------------------------------------------
```

Here 905, 924, 93E, 930, 93F are unicode for hindi characters.

Plz help , how can i print Hindi characters of Unicode? Which Zebra font (.FNT) should i use?

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The fonts you mentioned may not have the Hindi characters in them. Convert a TrueType font that has them (e.g., Mangal) to a Zebra FNT. The Zebra setup utility should be able to convert a TTF to an FNT for you.

Mangal comes with Windows. If you're not running Windows, you can find free Devanagari fonts lots of places online.